# How to run a Python script on your server and import libraries

Tags: python, server, libraries, python-import, pymysql

I'm currently launching my website and I want my Python script to be run. However, it does not work when I run it because it depends on 5 libraries. How do you link them to your code?
For example, I use pymysql to write data to my host's database. However, it does not recognise pymysql.
Is there a way to download all of the packages once on the server and then being able to access them? How to link to them in the code?

Many thanks !

Comment: Use pip to install them on the server.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, the easiest way is probably to use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get a list (requirements.txt) of the dependencies that you have installed for your project (which, if you're running under a virtualenv, is only those installed for your project).

If you have installed multiple libraries for your interpreter that you don't need, you can remove them from the list, or create the list manually.

You can make `pip` install all the libraries again on your host by doing `pip -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you have the steps to access your server and to "pip install" my packages there?

Comment: Usually that would be by logging in to the server through SSH, but there's probably admin panels that lets you invoke commands directly on the server as well. Depends on how your host has these things set up.

Comment: I'm facing an issue in the http.client.py which is "Traceback (most recent call last): File "./data.py", line 9, in from urllib.request import urlopen, Request File "/home/www/urllib/request.py", line 88, in import http.client File "/home/www/http/client.py", line 1063 chunk = f'{len(chunk):X}\r\n'.encode('ascii') + chunk \ ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax SyntaxError: invalid syntax1"

Comment: I really can't understand what's wrong in this file. I've uploaded the latest version of http.client.py

Comment: Please ask new questions as a new question and add your code properly formatted.

Comment: How do you put all the libraries listed in requirements.txt into a bundle along with your Python script

Comment: If you can't run pip on the host, you can create your own directory for libraries, bundle the libraries there and inject it into the import path when starting your script.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to package your project and deploy it on your remote server.

The best practices nowadays is described in “[Packaging and Distributing Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/)” from the Python Packaging Authority

You can follow the [Sample Python project](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject) available on GitHub.

Another way is to create a library or an application using a project template. One of the famous ones is [cookiecutter-pypackage](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage) from Audrey Roy Greenfeld [Cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the info you're looking for:

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9587/29/how-to-run-python-scripts

They give two solutions - the cPanel solution and the SSH solution.